# Residual diagnostic correlogram q statistics

Tags: autocorrelation, white-noise, eviews

I am trying to get information from the correlogram of residuals in eviews from a certain equation.  And it is stated that the p-values should be all greater than 0.05.  But all of my p Values are zero.  As it shows below: Plz help me understand these terms as for the validity of the equation all the values should be greater than .05. and if there is any need to include ar term how can we decide that and is it shows white noise?

Date: 10/17/16   Time: 14:48
Sample: 10/31/1994 3/28/2013
Included observations: 4575

Autocorrelation Partial Correlation     AC   PAC     Q-Stat  Prob

```
    |      |            |      |    1   0.070   0.070   22.552  0.000
    |      |            |      |    2   -0.031  -0.036  26.865  0.000
    |      |            |      |    3   0.003   0.008   26.908  0.000
    |      |            |      |    4   0.018   0.016   28.398  0.000
    |      |            |      |    5   -0.007  -0.009  28.635  0.000
    |      |            |      |    6   -0.054  -0.052  42.116  0.000
    |      |            |      |    7   0.007   0.014   42.334  0.000
    |      |            |      |    8   0.032   0.027   46.972  0.000
    |      |            |      |    9   0.027   0.024   50.336  0.000
    |      |            |      |    10  0.035   0.035   55.953  0.000
    |      |            |      |    11  -0.028  -0.033  59.440  0.000
    |      |            |      |    12  -0.017  -0.015  60.778  0.000
    |      |            |      |    13  0.013   0.014   61.579  0.000
    |      |            |      |    14  0.035   0.035   67.117  0.000
    |      |            |      |    15  -0.001  -0.001  67.120  0.000
    |      |            |      |    16  -0.005  -0.001  67.247  0.000
    |      |            |      |    17  0.036   0.031   73.319  0.000
    |      |            |      |    18  -0.029  -0.040  77.282  0.000
    |      |            |      |    19  -0.009  0.000   77.646  0.000
    |      |            |      |    20  -0.040  -0.038  84.939  0.000
    |      |            |      |    21  0.006   0.012   85.091  0.000
    |      |            |      |    22  -0.007  -0.012  85.325  0.000
    |      |            |      |    23  -0.003  -0.000  85.358  0.000
    |      |            |      |    24  0.021   0.016   87.339  0.000
    |      |            |      |    25  0.012   0.009   87.961  0.000
    |      |            |      |    26  -0.009  -0.012  88.349  0.000
    |      |            |      |    27  0.005   0.007   88.456  0.000
    |      |            |      |    28  -0.005  -0.003  88.560  0.000
    |      |            |      |    29  -0.030  -0.029  92.844  0.000
    |      |            |      |    30  -0.019  -0.012  94.530  0.000
    |      |            |      |    31  -0.005  -0.008  94.625  0.000
    |      |            |      |    32  -0.000  0.000   94.625  0.000
    |      |            |      |    33  -0.010  -0.009  95.072  0.000
    |      |            |      |    34  0.002   0.003   95.099  0.000
    |      |            |      |    35  -0.002  -0.004  95.112  0.000
    |      |            |      |    36  -0.002  -0.001  95.130  0.000
```